# How to Access Website Audio Source with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

So, I would like to use the Web Audio API to manipulate audio that is streaming from websites.  (For example, create a dynamic bass boost for listening via Soundcloud.)

I'm familiar with the Web Audio API and know how to use it to stream audio from the microphone or create a synthesizer.

**However, I cannot determine is the Web Audio API (or Javascript, in general) is capable of "grabbing" audio from an already existing audio source.  Is it possible to access audio from a site?**

Thanks.

Comment: "Javascript" can play audio (html5) or plugins as a player did, but what do you mean by access website audio source??

Comment: I want to push audio from a website, like Soundcloud or Pandora, into a Web Audio graph.  This in order to manipulate the audio with the Web Audio API.

Comment: You serve the mp3 from an api without allow origin header if you give the mp3 audio file. and then playing, simple example here : https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/JRaLVR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not something that the Web Audio API can do. Media elements must be available within the document to use them for a MediaElementAudioSourceNode.

(And it will probably never be possible on a cross-origin basis -- browser developers generally take a dim view of APIs that could potentially lead to information leaking across origins.)

Comment: That's what I thought.  Then I found this Chrome extension...
[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ears-bass-boost-eq-any-au/nfdfiepdkbnoanddpianalelglmfooik?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon]

Comment: @ErikKimsey Extensions can do a lot of things that web pages cannot.